# VBA - True or False, if string is found

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get a **True** or **False**, depending on, **if a string is found** in the worksheet "fal".

```
Dim stress As Boolean
If fal.UsedRange.Find("Approach = STRESS") > 0 Then
stress = True
Else
stress = False
End If
```

It gives a "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block not set"

Any ideas?

Comment: what string aer you triying to find? `Approach = STRESS`?

Comment: Yes, that's a string in a cell.

Comment: can you post the complete code? 'fal' is the name of your worksheet? have you referenced it in a variable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim stress As Boolean
stress = Not fal.UsedRange.Find("Approach = STRESS") Is Nothing
```

Comment: This works perfect! Thanks! I can accept the answer in 5 mins, after I am allowed to.

Comment: Actually No... It says that stress = False, when the string is obviously there...

Comment: @ViharChervenkov, see my updated answer - you should use `stress = Not fal.UsedRange.Find("Approach = STRESS") Is Nothing` - note there is `Not` before `fal.UsedRange.Find`